# Software for knotted $\mathbb{S}^2$'s in $\mathbb{S}^4$

Tags: geometry, general-topology, reference-request

According to the work of J. Scott Carter you can draw pictures of knotted surfaces in four-space in several different ways. I know the man is a real artist in this, but did anybody come across some software that does this for you ? See for example: http://www.jscottcarter.com/)

I guess you can figure out a parametric equation for a knotted sphere, and pay a trip to Mathematica-land, but I haven't done this.

This is probably a more specialized version of [Topology software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51284/topology-software))